Fluent Bit Multiple Log_Level Values
I have setup Fluent Bit with AWS EKS cluster, distributed as a deamonset.
And I wonder if it is possible to configure multiple Log_Levels values, under the [SERVICE] section, of Fleunt Bit configmap.
For Exsample,
I only want to log error and warning:
[SERVICE]
Log Level error, warning
is this possible, in Fleunt Bit?

From the docs, you cannot set multiple log levels in the SERVICE section.
If you haven't already, you should be setting up a Filter section to match the specific logs you are looking for, then overriding the Log_Level in that section. Filter docs say:

Log_Level: Set the plugin's logging verbosity level. Allowed values are: off, error, warn, info, debug and trace. Defaults to the SERVICE section's Log_Level.

Since SERVICE log_level is accumulative, e.g.

Values are accumulative, e.g: if 'debug' is set, it will include error, warning, info and debug.

And Filter defaults to the SERVICE log_level, you will get all logs of all log levels.
See the Service and Filter sections in the docs: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/classic-mode/configuration-file

thanks,regarding the point of the Log_level being accumulative,
So if "debug" is set, and will include: "error, warning, info and debug.
Will setting "info", will include: "error, warning and info"?

I don't know for certain, as it would depend on the logger used by fluentbit, but I would assume it would. E.g. INFO and anything above it: WARNING, ERROR, FATAL / CRITICAL.
